# Multidimensional binding

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

For dealing with two-dimensional matrices, `rbind` and `cbind` are useful functions. Are there more generic functions to perform the same operation in more dimensions? Suppose I have data like this:

```
data <- lapply(c(11,22,33), function(i) matrix(i, nrow=2, ncol=4))
```

What I'd like to obtain is this:

```
data <- do.call(c, data)
dim(data) <- c(2, 4, 3)
```

but without having to work out all the dimensions myself.

**Is there a function providing this functionality, either built-in or as part of a reasonably common package?** Or do you want to share your own ideas of how such a function could be implemented most elegantly?

Bonus points:

- If the function gives some control over the order of dimensions, then a subsequent call to `aperm` could be avoided.
- It would be nice if it could operate by *either* passing multiple function arguments *or* a `list` of arguments, although using `do.call` or `list`, either one will suffice.
- I'd like to use such a function as the `.combine` argument to a [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) call. So it should be able to construct multi-dimensional matrices using calls of the form `f(f(f(a, b), c), d)` (each call takes exactly two arguments, the first usually the result of the previous call) or even `f(f(a, b), c, d)` (more than two arguments, the first still might be the result of the previous call), with `a, b, c, d` all of the same size, resulting in a matrix with a dimension 1 higher than the dimensions of these and a size of 4 in that dimension, corresponding to the 4 elements `a` through `d`.

Comment: There is a package called **abind** with a function of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [abind](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/abind/index.html) package has precisely this function, with most of the features you mention, although I haven't checked all of them in detail.

At the very least, it would give you a start on how one would implement something along these lines.